plainto_tsquery returns empty result for string 'what'
I'm converting search text to tsquery with plainto_tsquery function. When running the following statement
select plainto_tsquery('english'::regconfig, 'what');

I get empty result. Server is: "PostgreSQL 13.13 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by Debian clang version 12.0.1, 64-bit".
What could be the reason for that?

It's because you haven't read the manuals:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS
=> SELECT to_tsvector('french', 'what is it') AS fr, to_tsvector('english', 'what is it') AS en;
┌────────────────────────┬────┐
│           fr           │ en │
├────────────────────────┼────┤
│ 'is':2 'it':3 'what':1 │    │
└────────────────────────┴────┘
(1 row)


Manuals are huge and I use PostgreSQL once in a full moon, so I can be excused I didn't find that at the time of writing the question. I found it later and when I returned here to close the question, I found it closed already. But good advice would be to use simple language to retain all the words.
